# HashSet as DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I am trying to optimize the code for SharePoint webpart. I have a repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CountryOptionsRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <option value='<%#Eval("CountryName") %>'><%#Eval("CountryName") %></option>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am filling it with data-table

```
countriesList = countriesList.Distinct<String>().ToList<String>();
countriesList.Sort();
//var noDupsCountriesList = new HashSet<String>(countriesList);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("CountryName");

foreach (String countryName in countriesList)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["CountryName"] = countryName;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

CountryOptionsRepeater.DataSource = dt;
CountryOptionsRepeater.DataBind();
this.DataBind();
```

Is there a way to directly bind HashSet object (noDupsCountriesList) to DataSource with same configuration of repeater, in order to bring about optimization?

Something like:

```
//countriesList = countriesList.Distinct<String>().ToList<String>();
//countriesList.Sort();
var noDupsCountriesList = new HashSet<String>(countriesList);

CountryOptionsRepeater.DataMember = "CountryName"; // ??
CountryOptionsRepeater.DataSource = noDupsCountriesList;
CountryOptionsRepeater.DataBind();
this.DataBind();
```

Comment: why does you need the DataTable or HashSet? Would `CountryOptionsRepeater.DataSource = countriesList;` not do the trick?

Comment: It might be possible to do the binding directly to the `HashSet<>`, but it won't give you the countries sorted alphabetically, that from your code appears to be necessary.

Comment: @MiMo, thanks I would add `OrderBy` statement (with the assumption that HashSet's `initializaiton + OrderBy` is much more optimized than calling List<>'s `Distinct() + ToList() + Sort()`)..

Comment: in that case, `CountryOptionsRepeater.DataSource = countriesList.Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToList();`, and yes, you can use DataSource with any `IEnumerable<>`

Answer (score 6):

I think this line could replace your second block of code:

```
CountryOptionsRepeater.DataSource = 
    countriesList
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(c => c)
    .Select(c => new { CountryName = c })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's throwing an error: Cannot find the column name `CountryName`. Should I use `<HeadingTemplate>` in ascx file (as the List doesn't have the column heading)?

Comment: The DataMember should be left empty if a primitive type is used. DataMember is meant to specify a property on the type.